# ghci: how to import modules in a folder

Tags: haskell, ghci

After updating from ghc 7.6 to 7.10 it seems you can't `:m [Module]` or `ghci> import [Module]` where [Module.hs] is your hand-written module file that resides in current working directory.

It seems ghci searches only for modules that are part of haskell standard library and modules that are globally installed via cabal. (you can still `:load [Module.hs]` in ghci prompts though)

I think it's kinda annoying since you can't test whether my module definition is correct by directly importing them from ghci. Is there any switch or configuration that I can fiddle with, so I can tell where my haskell working dirctory is to ghci?

Comment: just throw a `.cabal` into the folder exposing your module and it should work

Comment: I don't understand. If `:load` works, why not just use that?

Comment: You can still use `:m` or `import` on "local" modules, it's just that now all modules must be loaded before calling either of these commands on them (I believe it would previously load the module automatically if it wasn't loaded?). So just do `:l Module.hs ; :m + Module`.

Comment: The answer and comment above have it right; I just want to point out that [#7416](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7416) is relevant. You can load multiple modules with `:l Module1.hs Module2.hs ...`, but only `Module1.hs` is imported. You have to `:m +Module2 ...` to import the rest.

Comment: @sclv `:load` is slightly different, it loads all functions in the file, not just the ones exported by the module (i.e. `module Foo (a,b,c) where...`).

Answer (score 7):

Not a very useful way, but if you want to achieve this old behavior, you have to load the file that contains the module

```
ghci> :l File.hs
```

Hide/remove all the modules you don't want

```
ghci> :m
```

The module imported from the file is now available

```
ghci> :m YourModule
```